# AngularJS Not counting newlines in var length

Tags: angularjs

When I enter some text and then enter some new lines using `test.length` does not count new lines in the string.  I'm using this text to send SMS messages which are sensitive to all newlines so it all has to count.  Any ideas?

Hit enter 4 times and see the counter doesn't go up.

http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/HJAfn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an [`ng-trim="false"`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.text) to avoid automatic trimming: http://codepen.io/musically_ut/pen/KHBto

The documentation for this is missing but there is an [pull request on the way](https://github.com/cesutherland/angular.js/commit/39298caf51178dbd30a37fcb724edbbe8b299103).

Comment: Hmm... did not know about ng-trim. Thanks for expanding my knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The control characters for CRLF (\r\n) typically don't count in the length of a string. You can detect them with a matching regex and use the number of matches to increment your character count. Something like this:

```
var crlfCount = mytext.match(/[\n\r]|[\r\n]/g);
linecount += crlfCount.length;
```